# SPO: Using JSON to Show/Hide Modern Form Field Based on Value Selected in Lookup Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, modern-experience, list-form, json-formatting

I am trying to modify the new-entry form of a modern list in SharePoint Online by hiding or showing a field based on the value selected in a preceding field on the same form. [Microsoft offers straightforward guidance](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide) on how to do this using a JSON snippet.

While they don't list a lookup column as an unsupported field type to use for this purpose, they don't provide guidance on how to use one in this way, either. And from my testing, you can't simply grab the value of a lookup field in the described way:

```
=if([$LookupField]=='Hourly', 'true', 'false')
```

If I use a choice field instead of a lookup field, this works fine. But doing some digging, in other contexts it looks like the value may be captured in a `.lookupValue` property, so I tried it this way:

```
=if([$LookupField.lookupValue]=='Hourly', 'true', 'false')
```

Still no luck. Does anyone know if it is possible to use the value from a lookup field in this way? And if so, what do I need to do to make the magic happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After debugging, I found that the validation function receives the lookup field values in this format: `<Lookup ID>;#<Lookup Title>`:

[image]

In your case, if the Hourly item has an id of 1, then the JSON formulata should be written this way:

```
=if([$LookupField]=='1;#Hourly', 'true', 'false')
```

**Proof that it works**

[image]

**Update**

If you want to avoid "hardcoding" specific lookup ID in the formula, you should use this formula to compare the lookup with a [specific Text value](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide#lookup-column):

```
=if(substring([$City],indexOf([$City],';#')+2,1000) == 'Toronto', 'true', 'false')
```

Comment: Denis, I tried your recommendation and it does not seem to make any difference. Were you able to test this in practice, hiding and showing one form field based on the result returned by a lookup field? If so, I am stumped why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Absolutely, I have tested my aswer before posting it.

Comment: Denis, I retried this and can confirm that you are absolutely correct. It does work. The need for the additional click may have given me some trouble, but I think I may have originally applied the wrong ID value to the ID/value combination. This is an impressive find. Thank you for sharing it.

Answer (score 1):

Lookup fields are not supported in conditional formulas in SharePoint.

**Source**: [can we show a column in a form based on a lookup field?](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/6249)

---

**Update**:

Lookup column examples are added to Microsoft official documentation now: [Show or hide columns in a list or library form-Lookup column](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide#lookup-column)

Comment: Thanks, Ganesh. Disappointing, but in alignment with what I am seeing. I have created a UserVoice entry to request this capability: https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/43186173-enable-the-ability-to-hide-sharepoint-form-fields

Comment: Please, see the screenshot in my answer.

Comment: Ganesh, after retesting, I can confirm that the approach Denis proposed does work. It does have a quirk of requiring an additional click outside the control in order to force the appearance of the hidden control. Ideally Microsoft will recraft this to allow a single click and the use of .lookupValue or .lookupId or something similar, but even as-is, this is a very useful capability.